# How to set default 'uuid-ossp' extension to all migration files using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-postgresql

How to set default 'uuid-ossp' extension to all migration files?

enable_extension 'uuid-ossp'

I'm using Ruby 2.1 and Rails 4 and PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rails 4 has native support for the type UUID (Universally Unique Identifier) in Postgres. Here I will describe how you can use it for generating `UUIDs` without doing it manually in your Rails code.

First you need to enable the `Postgres` extension `‘uuid-ossp’`:

```
class CreateUuidPsqlExtension < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    enable_extension "uuid-ossp"
  end

  def self.down
    disable_extension "uuid-ossp"
  end
end
```

You can use a `UUID` as a `ID` replacement:

```
create_table :translations, id: :uuid do |t|
  t.string :title
  t.timestamps
end
```

In this case the Translations table will have a UUID as ID and it is autogenerated. The uuid-ossp extension in Postgresq has different algorithms how the UUID is generated. Rails 4 uses v4 per default. You can read more about these algorithms here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/uuid-ossp.html

However, sometimes you don't want to have the UUID as ID replacement and instead have it in a separate column:

```
class AddUuidToModelsThatNeedIt < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :translations, :uuid, :uuid
  end

  def down
    remove_column :translations, :uuid
  end
end
```

This will create a `UUID` column, but the UUID will not be autogenerated. You have to do it yourself in Rails with SecureRandom. However, we think that this is a typical database responsibility. Fortunately, the default option in `add_column` helps:

```
class AddUuidToModelsThatNeedIt < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :translations, :uuid, :uuid, :default => "uuid_generate_v4()"
  end

  def down
    remove_column :translations, :uuid
  end
end
```

Now the `UUID` will be created `automatically`, also for **existing records**!

I hope this help you to understand.. If this post satisfied you to understand UUID then kindly up-vote this answer... ;)
via Helmut

Comment: I'm asking enable default to all migartions

Answer (score 0):

To change the migrations that are generated by Rails you can [modify the templates (follow the guide)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#customizing-your-workflow-by-changing-generators-templates). The template you want to modify is: [active_record/migration/create_table_migration.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/rails/generators/active_record/migration/templates/create_table_migration.rb)

On the other hand you can also [customize the config](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#customizing-your-workflow) to make [this generator](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/rails/generators/active_record/migration.rb) use the primary key you want:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.primary_key_type             :uuid
end
```